# I need to do OpenGL texturing with certain color transparent

Tags: opengl

Still, I am using OpenGL 1.x;
 I could blit a 24bit targa image in OpenGL. Let's say I got a targa file with a monster on it.
its background is blue. How could I dicard this blue information?

An alternative: I know lesson32 in NeHe tutorial used a 32bit targa, Yeah, I could display it in my application. Here a new problem arises: How could I create 32bit TGA with certain area transparent. I don't get the point of the NeHe explanation.

here is my way in photoshop which does not work:

1. Create a new file, put the
   background layer into the trash and
   create a transparent layer.
2. Create a selection on the
   transparent layer and fill it with
   some solid color,say ,red.
3. Save the file as a 32bit TGA and
   blit in my OpenGL app.

To my dismay, the region I thought should have been transparent is now pure white...
(the image loading method has no problem, as it can load some other good 32bit targas)

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking in the terms of colour keying. But what you should use is a alpha channel. This is an additional channel, not being colour, but opaquenes value. In Photoshop you get this, by *NOT* filling the transparent parts with anything.